# jqGrid GET and POST mtype in MVC

Tags: model-view-controller, jqgrid, mvcjqgrid

I just read that the mtype option in the jqGrid will determine how we will do the ajax call. GET will retrieve data and POST will send data.

When i load my jqGrid, i want to pass an extra parameter to my controller, in my js file:

```
url: 'Controller/Action1',
mtype: 'POST',
datatype: 'json',
postData: { ParentId:  selectedParentId },
```

In my controller I have this:

```
public JsonResult Action1(ParentId)
{
 // Retrieve child properties from db using ParentId
 // Return json result
}
```

1. How will my jqGrid load the returned json data if my mtype is POST?
2. In my action, could i still get the other options of my jqGrid as a parameter like sort order, page size selected? Could i use something like `this.Request.Param["sidx"]` in my action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller you would take all the parameters the jqGrid would pass you:

```
public ActionResult GetGridData(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, bool _search, string filters, string ParentId)
{
 ....
 int totalRecords = wholeList.Count();
 var pagedQuery = wholeList.OrderBy(sidx + " " + sord).Skip((page - 1) * rows).Take(rows).ToList();

        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = (totalRecords + rows - 1) / rows,
            page = page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = (
            from tempItem in pagedQuery
            select new
               {
                cell = new string[] {
                    tempItem.ToString(),
                    ...


               }
            }).ToArray()

 return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

You can use the extra parameter to change what you feed back to the jqGrid, and you will also see you are passing in and using the parameters to handle paging.

Answer (score 1):

1. mtype option defines the type of the HTTP request:

   - if it's set to GET (by default): the request parameters are appended in the http query in the Addressbar like this .../Controller/Action1?ParentId=selectedParentId
   - if it's set to POST, the request parameters are hidden when sending http query 
     In fact, the two methods send the same parameters with diffrent ways. So there is any diffrent on loading returned JSON data with GET or POST method
2. Or course you can get the other options of your jqGrid as a parameter like sort order

Sorry for my bad english